# Calling Text in Javascript

Tags: javascript, notepad++

people! I'm new to using Javascript outside of CodeHS; I'm using Notepad++. I'm messing around with it to see what I can do, and i ran into a problem. More or less, I have a question.

```
function update(){
    x += spdX;
    y += spdY;
    ctx.fillText('P', x, y);
    console.log('P has moved', x);
}
```

I took a snippet here from my code. As you can see, I have made a text using `ctx.fillText('P', x, y);`, but I'm having a problem. I would like to know how to *identify* the text. Let's say I want to put the 'P' into a variable, how would I do that?(Example: `var pos = getText('P');`), is that a possibility? Thanks for helping!

Comment: Once you have drawn something to a canvas, all that is known is that there are some pixels there. If you want to preserve meaningful data when drawing shapes, you'd be better off using SVG instead.

Comment: It's not a good idea to use the DOM as the source of truth. Save your values in variables and print out to the page. If you later try to pull items out of the page, you'll have a bad time.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Could you explain what SVG & DOM are, please?